# How to retrieve classpath used by maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I work on a very large Java project. The project has a top-level `pom.xml` file, which specifies various 3rd-party dependencies. The top-level `pom.xml` file also specifies various submodules, one of which being the one I'd like to modify.

My goal is to define a goal to run `java -h` to generate JNI header files. This is what I have so far:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-jni-headers</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <executable>javac</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--class-path</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</argument>
            <argument>-h</argument>
            <argument>${project.basedir}/path_to_include_folder</argument>
            <argument>${project.basedir}/path_to_java_class_file_to_be_processed</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, `javac` complains about many packages to not exist. At least most of these unresolved packages correspond to those that are specified as 3rd-party dependencies in the top-level `pom.xml` file.

How can I modify the code above to provide `javac` with the same classpath information that is being used by `maven-compiler-plugin` to compile the code?

Comment: add `<classpath/>` after `<argument>--class-path</argument>`: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#arguments

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Can you please be more specific. I just had a look at the documentation and I am not sure how to use your suggestion to solve my problem.

Comment: There are examples by the link: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks man!! I got it to work now. Wow, the way this has to be done feels really so hacky. What a terrible build system.